# Dynamic Lambda condition on nested array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamic-linq

I want to perform a Dynamic Lambda in a collection with an array of strings[] on it:

```
public class ClassStudentsViewModel
{
    public string[] Disciplines { get; set; }
    public TeacherName { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm trying:

[image]

The `source` is a collection of `ClassStudentsViewModel` and the `values` is an array of strings with one string. When executed, it throws me this exception:

> No property or field 'y' exists in type 'String'

After some searching, I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5152764/1267304) which is almost the same problem and the OP ended *changing* the source code of Dynamic.cs, that isn't a nice option for me. I wonder what I'm trying isn't supported or might be a bug. The problem is that the above mantioned question was asked almost 4 years ago.

The following snippet works nice:

```
classStudents.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Disciplines.Any(y => y == "Turma 2")).ToList();
```

How can I get rid of that error?

**UPDATE:**

A little context of what I'm trying: My controller receives a viewModel with a collection of filters sent by the 3rd party grid, which contains basically a *value* and a *operator*, like `eq`, `gt` etc... A method loops all those filters and transforms on lambda operators, like `eq` to `==` or `contains` to `.Contains()`. In a simple string property like `TeacherName`(updated viewModel above), the dynamic filters works, e.g. if the `predicate` in the screenshot is: `"TeacherName.Contains(@0)"` it works well.

**UPDATE 2:**

This code generates the predicate:

```
public static string ToLambdaOperator(string field, string oper, int index, string sufix = null)
{
    var result = String.Empty;

    switch (oper)
    {
        case "eq":
        case "neq":
        case "gte":
        case "gt":
        case "lte":
        case "lt":
            result = string.Format(field + ToLinqOperator(oper) + "@" + index);
            break;

        case "startswith":
            result = field + ".StartsWith(" + "@" + index + ")";
            break;

        case "endswith":
            result = field + ".EndsWith(" + "@" + index + ")";
            break;

        case "contains":
            result = field + ".Contains(" + "@" + index + ")";
            break;

        case "doesnotcontain":
            result = "!" + field + ".Contains(" + "@" + index + ") || " + field + ".Equals(String.Empty)";
            break;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sufix))
    {
        result += sufix;
    }

    return result;
}

// Use example
var operator = "eq";
var paramCounter = -1;
var predicate = ToLambdaOperator("Disciplines.Any(y => y", operator, ++paramCounter, ")");
```

The predicate above will result: `Disciplines.Any(y => y == @0)`. With the operator `contains` will result in this: `Disciplines.Any(y => y.Contains(@0))`.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to use dynamic LINQ at all here. What's dynamic in your case?

Comment: @JonSkeet I build that expression outside for filtering a 3rd party grid widget.

Comment: That's not a terribly clear description - it doesn't give us much more context. Could you perform *this* part of the query with normal LINQ to Objects, then use that as a source for dynamic LINQ for the widget integration?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to include all the relevant information without posting hundreds of lines. I've updated, I hope it clearifies the question. Btw, the question I linked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152764/how-can-i-make-it-possible-to-use-a-dynamic-lambda-in-dynamic-linq) haves the same problem in a different explanation.

Comment: If you're already writing code to handle each operator separately, I don't see why you'd want to use dynamic LINQ - I'd just convert each operator to a `Func<T, bool>` for the relevant type... the more you can do in "normal" LINQ to Objects, the easier it will be.

Comment: @JonSkeet nice, I will search for that because I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: provide us with predicate variable, where do you declare it and how do you assign it ?

Comment: @user2397162 the `predicate` content is built in a method which reads some filters and transform them into lambda methods. Just that.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I think the error is within it, you're trying to access a Y property of an object that doesn't have because it's a String

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown posting the code of this method which assigns predicate would be helpful I think

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is to generate an expression tree based on the arguments provided. Here are some examples about how to do that.

https://gist.github.com/afreeland/6733381

[How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx)